# How to add one year to a DateTime in a leap Year

Tags: php, datetime, php-7.2

I want to get the last day of the month of the next year from a given date

Here is how I did :

```
$copy = new \DateTime();
$lastDay = new \DateTime($copy->add((new \DateInterval('P1Y')))->format('Y-m-t'));
```

This works exept in this exemple :

```
$copy = new \DateTime('2024-02-29');
$lastDay = new \DateTime($copy->add((new \DateInterval('P1Y')))->format('Y-m-t'));
```

It returns me '2025-03-31' while I want '2025-02-28'

Comment: "Reset" to first day of the month first, then advance by one year, and then get the number of days ...

Comment: `$copy->modify('first day of next year')->format('Y-m-t');`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution :

```
$lastDay = $copy->modify('first day of next year last day of this month');
```

Thanks to shingo

Comment: Think 'next year last day of this month' does the same.